# Load .csv to SQL Server run on Docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, dockerfile, localhost

How can I load `*.csv` file from local to dockerized SQL Server which runs on the same local machine (I'm a beginner in docker, I do everything on my computer, not on server or cloud).

I follow the tutorial [dockerizing-r-shiny-and-ms-sql-server](https://towardsdatascience.com/dockerizing-r-shiny-and-ms-sql-server-a-concise-introduction-part-1-c329a5636ece).

Load SQL script:

```
CREATE DATABASE app_db;
GO

USE app_db;
GO

CREATE TABLE iris 
(
    Sepal_Length numeric(10,5), 
    Sepal_Width numeric(10,5), 
    Petal_Length numeric(10,5), 
    Petal_Width numeric(10,5), 
    Species VARCHAR(20)
);
GO

BULK INSERT iris
FROM 'C:\DockerTutorial\iris.csv'
WITH
    (FIRSTROW = 2,
     FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
     ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
     TABLOCK)
GO

UPDATE iris
SET Species = REPLACE(Species, CHAR(34), '')
```

This is response:

```
c:\DockerTutorial>sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P MyPassword123! -d master -i C:\DockerTutorial\load_data.sql
Changed database context to 'app_db'.
Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Server 76301548ccf4, Line 2
Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\DockerTutorial\iris.csv" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

(0 rows affected)
```

Comment: Paths for the SQL Server in Docker will be in respect of the Container Environment. The file will need to be in the docker environment, or in a location that the container has access to, and you'll need to use the path to the specific mount point in the container.

Comment: @Larnu Pls, can you giv eme example? Where can I save my .csv or how can I them put to Container Enviroment?

Comment: A [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=copy+file+to+docker+container) will give you lots of examples.